# Creating bracket-enclosed, colored, hyperlinked text

Tags: hyperref, color, brackets, href

How do I surround a hyperlink with square brackets using `\href`?

I want something like [Link] with square brackets, in black and "Link" in blue (my default hyper-link color).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This way the square brackets are also part of the link, but take the color of the main text (black by default):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\newcommand\mylink[2]{\href{#1}{[{\color{blue}#2}]}}
\begin{document}
This is a
\mylink{http://www.example.com}{Example} 
web.  
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, urlcolor=blue]{hyperref} 
\let\oldhref\href
\renewcommand\href[2]{[\oldhref{#1}{#2}]}
\begin{document} 
    Here is the \href{https://tex.stackexchange.com/}{Tex Site}. More text ...
\end{document}
```

[image: Output]